# test if user is logged in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am making a test but it fails when it tries to check if a user is logged in:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class RegisterTest extends TestCase
{

    use RefreshDatabase;

    /*.....
    more test about registering
     ....*/    

    /** @test */
    function redirect_to_home_page_and_logged_in_after_login()
    {                   

        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'name' => 'Test',
            'email' => 'test@hotmail.com', 
            'password' => '123456'
        ]);     

        $response = $this->post('login', [
            'email' => 'test@hotmail.com',
            'password' => '123456'          
        ]);

        //this works
        $response->assertRedirect('/');

        //this fails 
        $this->assertTrue(Auth::check());


    }
}
```

And this is my controller HomeController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {                    

        if (Auth::check()){

            return view('home');    
        }

        return view('welcome');

    }
}
```

And this is my routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');    
Auth::routes();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. What can I do?. I am using laravel 5.7 and phpunit 5.7.1
Also in my app/Htpp/Auth/LoginController.php I did this:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

Thank you.

Comment: I will take a wild guess and say that you are actually never logged in because you didn't `bcrypt()` your password in the factory. However, I am not really sure. Can you give it a try?

Comment: I had forgotten the bcrypt() function. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a user requires you to take care of the hashing of the password.
You can simply do it by using php's [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. And use `Auth::login($user);` to login.

Like so:

```
$user = User::create(['email' => 'r@o.b', 'password' => password_hash('123456', 1)]);
Auth::login($user); //You should be logged in :)
```

Comment: This is not the solution about what the author asked... the correct solution was given by Mike Harrison...

Comment: You shouldn't use the password_hash function - laravel has a built in function called `bcrypt` that is more secure

Answer (score 9):

In addition to hashing your password you could also just post to the register route and create a new account.

```
/** @test */
function redirect_to_home_page_and_logged_in_after_register()
{                      
    $response = $this->post('register', [
        'name' => 'Test',
        'email' => 'test@hotmail.com',
        'password' => '123456'          
    ]);

    //this works
    $response->assertRedirect('/');

    //this fails 
    $this->assertTrue(Auth::check());
}
```

I guess you may also have a requirement to do it both ways:

```
/** @test */
function redirect_to_home_page_and_logged_in_after_login()
{                

    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'name' => 'Test',
        'email' => 'test@hotmail.com', 
        // note you need to use the bcrypt function here to hash your password
        'password' => bcrypt('123456')
    ]);      

    $response = $this->post('login', [
        'name' => 'Test',
        'email' => 'test@hotmail.com',
        'password' => '123456'          
    ]);

    //this works
    $response->assertRedirect('/');

    //this fails 
    $this->assertTrue(Auth::check());
}
```